# How does Death Fire Touch work when hitting enemies with multiple skills?

Tags: league-of-legends

Death Fire Touch deals different amounts of damage depending on the skill used to apply it. I'm most interested in what happens when playing Cassiopeia. Q is a damage over time skill and applies it for 1 second but E is single target and applies for 4 seconds.

If I hit an enemy with E to apply it for 4 seconds, is it overridden with a 1 second duration if I land a Q or will it keep the remainder of the 4 seconds?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it overrides it with the new duration and effect (since I don't think Deathfire Touch can stack on targets), but unfortunately I don't have an official source for this.

Comment: Correct, 100% certain it cannot stack. Fairly certain that it overrides the current duration. No source other than my own playing and watching it happen, you can see how long the effect is on you above your skills. Guess you have to be careful not to lose damage, I don't use deathfire touch often so I've never really thought about that, +1 good question. I'd like to see if someone has a real answer, I'd love to be wrong because losing damage like that seems like a hard decision to make since your skills should theoretically do more damage, but then make your passive much less useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [wikia page on Death Fire Touch](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Deathfire_Touch)

> - Deathfire Touch is a spell effect and will only be applied to instances of ability damage.
> - The damage from this mastery does not trigger itself nor other spell effects.
> - Multiple instances of damage will refresh the duration but does not stack.
>     & On DoTs the duration of the effect is: DoT's duration + 1 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple instances of Deathfire Touch do not stack, and will simply refresh the duration based on the last ability hit.